# Elegant way to count alphanumeric chars in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, alphanumeric

I am looking for an elegant way, preferably a short linq expression, to count how many alphanumeric chars a given string contains.

The 'boring' way I do it now is this:

```
int num = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < password.Length; i++)
{
    if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(password, i))
    {
        num++;
    }
}
if (num < MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters)
    return false;
```

This is rather short already, but I am sure with some linq magic this can be done in an even shorter, equally understandable expression, right?

Comment: The linq way won't lend itself as well to a very good optimization, which is to stop searching the string once you have enough alphanumeric characters. Okay given the context of passwords and their length, maybe it's not a 'very good' optimization...

Comment: @corsiKa i don't think he's going for optimization so much elegant-tizing/syntactic sugaring...

Comment: That's right, I am doing PBKDF2 hashing right after that part, so a few milliseconds here are not the issue anyway.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's the quick and dirty LINQ way to get the letter & digit count:

```
password.Count(char.IsLetterOrDigit)
```

This is more of a direct copy of what you're doing:

```
password.Count(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
```

Comment: If this actually works, it will be hard to beat in terms of length. Well done, sir.

Answer (score 2):

```
int num = password.Where((t, i) => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(password, i)).Count();

if (num < MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters)
    return false;
```

Comment: The Where is unnecessary here as you can do the same check in Count

Comment: @AustinSalonen as you can see various ways have already been showed on this page as answers, I personally find Where easy to use, its the first extension method that comes in my mind

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with one line of Regex. Whether that's understandable is a moot point.

```
num = new Regex(@"\w", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Matches(input).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Take()` to ensure that you don't inspect more letters than necessary:

```
int minCount = password.Where(x => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(x)).Take(MinRequired).Count();
if (minCount < MinRequired) { // No good }
```

The idea is that we only keep checking until you've hit the minimum number. At that point, we can stop, because we know we have an admissible password. `Take()` takes as many as it can, and no more, so if there aren't enough, it will just return a number less than you've requested.