# Counting number of occurrences of characters from array in string?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm writing code to determine whether a password contains enough punctuation characters.

How do I count the number of occurrences of any characters from a set?

Something along these lines:

```
private const string nonAlphaNumericCharSet = "#*!?£$+-^<>[]~()&";
...
public static bool PasswordMeetsStrengthRequirements(string password)
{
    return password.Length >= MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH && password.NumberOfOccurences(nonAlphaNumericCharSet.ToCharArray()) >= MINIMUM_NONALPHANUMERIC_CHARS;
}
```

Bonus points for an elegant linq solution.

Comment: How do you give out bonus points?

Comment: @Oliver: I guess Black Knight will be awarding a bounty (after the 24 hour wait period).

Comment: I was thinking about awarding upvotes. And of course my own personal gratitude ;). However, if people think an answer deserves a bounty then I'll award one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12899943/706456

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569951/elegant-way-to-count-alphanumeric-chars-in-a-string

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> How do I count the number of occurences of any characters from a set?

```
var count = password.Count(nonAlphaNumericCharSet.Contains);
```

Comment: +1, slick ..........., for those like me, its simpler form would be: `var temp = password.Count(r=> nonAlphaNumericCharSet.Contains(r));`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was just wondering what the simpler form would be.

Comment: @Carra, yes by just 6 minutes.

Comment: That and it's also more efficient :)

Answer (score 1):

you can count like this

```
int count = "he!l!l!o".Split('!').Length - 1;
```

it will return 3.

Using linq

```
int count="he!l!l!o".Count(x => x == '!');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
private const string nonAlphaNumericCharSet = "#*!?£$+-^<>[]~()&";

public static bool PasswordMeetsStrengthRequirements(string password)
{
    return password.Count(x => nonAlphaNumericCharSet.Contains(x)) > 2 && password.Length > 1;
}

public static void Main()
{
    PasswordMeetsStrengthRequirements("Test").Dump();
    PasswordMeetsStrengthRequirements("Test#").Dump();
    PasswordMeetsStrengthRequirements("(Test#").Dump();
    PasswordMeetsStrengthRequirements("(Te[st#").Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what about a [RegExp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx#regex_vs_string)

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^(?=.*(\W.*){4,}).{8,}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
bool validPassword = rgx.IsMatch(password);
```

4=min not word/digit char

8= min password leght

Linq may be considered elegant (it isn't IMHO) but at which performance cost?

------------Update after comment---------------

if you want to match a subset of chars you have to replace `\W` with `[]`

`[]`= range of chars

some chars have to be escaped with `\`

in your case: `[#\*!\?£\$\+-\^\<\>\[\]~\(\)&]`

there you can find a [regular expression cheat sheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Regexs are powerful but I'm not very good at them. It's important in this case however, to only match punctuation from a predefined set, not just all punctuation. How would I do that with a regex?

Comment: @BlackKnight just updated my answer. I'm not good at regular expression either. I find very usefull this cheatsheet: https://github.com/shadowbq/Cheat-Sheets/blob/master/regex/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2.pdf i have printed it and it is always near my desk!